# Trouble with .FBX importing/rendering

Tags: rendering, import, .fbx

I've been trying to open up this FBX package and get a render like the below preview, but Blender is really messed up when I try to open it. I've tried in 3 different version of Blender and tried using an add-on for importing the FBX and the glTF version of the package. Nothing has worked.

I've tried around 15 different 3D asset tools and haven't had any luck, with issues varying from failed imports to missing textures and lighting. I just want something that will give me the view in the preview below and render it.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

[FBX package](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_n-gTHD7elYHveyfvHD4feDPo4uGH4jV)

[image: asset preview]

Answer (score 0):

When you select the fbx file, there is an option to "Import User Properties" if you turn this off the file imports without error.

[image]